# Can I block Chrome's notification with Mac's Do Not Disturb?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I don't want to get notification while I'm working so I want to disable Chrome's all notification (Settings -> Show Advanced Settings -> Privacy -> Content Settings -> Do not allow any site to show notifications)  from Mac's Do Not Disturb mode?

Is it automize with Automator or something else?

Comment: Hi, does my answer solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, no I still keep getting notifications.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you get them through Chrome or macOS's notification center?

Comment: Chrome notification center

Comment: Oh, unfortunately it's not possible, you can use an extension though. I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I finally found a solution for this.

Change the following propery

```
chrome://flags/#enable-native-notifications
```

as ON. After that you can see all Chrome notification's from Mac's default notification center so it will work if you enable do not disturb mode from Mac's settings.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for me.  I'm still getting noise from one tab (Messages for the Web) even when DnD is turned on.  As this answer was over 3 years old, maybe Google broke it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's actually not possible to disable Chrome's notifications using Apple's Do Not Disturb mode. Chrome's notifications are sent through Chrome itself and not through Mac's notifications center. So, the only way is to use an extension or block them through Chrome's Settings page.

Google has a [support article](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?hl=en) regarding this.

---

Blocking notifications and hiding them are different.

Blocking notifications means that you can't get to receive them, neither can you check on them when you're free. However, hiding them means that you won't receive it at that time, but they will be available in the notifications centre.

---

You can block notifications by going to (Settings -> Show Advanced Settings -> Privacy -> Content Settings -> Do not allow any site to show notifications).

If you want to hide them for the time being, you can turn on your Mac's Do Not Disturb mode or simply click the ‘Chrome’ menu in the Menu Bar and select the ‘Hide Notifications Icon’ option.

Comment: I found a solution. If we merge Chrome notification's with Mac's native notification center. It will work